# Kotlin MongoDB, Get request won't work using the @PathVariable command

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

***Controller:***

```
   @GetMapping("/{id}/")
    suspend fun getProject(@PathVariable pidString: String): ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println(pidString)
            val pid = projectService.validateURLProjectId(pidString)
            ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.getProject(pid))
        }
    }
```

***`API Request:`***

```
http://localhost:8080/65461bff3f2baf0938c6f22e/
```

The id definitely exists

***Error***

```
{
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "code": 400,
    "timestamp": "2023-11-04T14:07:32.925505",
    "message": "500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR \"pidString\""
}
```

The problem is, it won't even get to the println(pidString) line, in the console, which makes me think it's something to do with @PathVariable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with how you're using the @PathVariable annotation in your Kotlin Spring application.

**Check if your Controller is properly mapped**

Make sure that your controller is properly mapped to the correct URL pattern. In your case, it seems like you're expecting a request at `http://localhost:8080/{id}/`, so double-check if your controller class or the method itself is properly annotated with `@RestController` and if the request mapping is correct.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/your-endpoint") // Add the endpoint mapping
class YourController {
    // ...
}
```

**Ensure you have the `@PathVariable` annotation correctly**

Double-check that you're using the `@PathVariable` annotation correctly on the `pidString` parameter in your `getProject` method.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/")
suspend fun getProject(@PathVariable("id") pidString: String): ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the value inside `@PathVariable` should match the parameter name in your URL.

**Check if your `projectService` is working as expected**

Make sure that `projectService.validateURLProjectId(pidString)` and `projectService.getProject(pid)` are working correctly. If there's an issue within these methods, it could cause an error.

**Check your `ProjectDTO` class**

Ensure that `ProjectDTO` class is properly defined and that it's not causing any issues.

Comment: @PathVariable("id") - I forgot to put ("id") after @PathVariable. That fixed it! thanks!